# Going to an endless loop trying to implement A star in java

Tags: java, infinite-loop, a-star, heuristics, sliding-tile-puzzle

I've been trying for two days to get this running, but I cant for the life of me.
what I'm trying to do is solve an 8 puzzle using the A star algorithm and manhattan heuristic.

this is the part of the code for the A star:

```
                        public void solve(){

    State s = duplicateState(stateToSolve);
    StringState ss = new StringState(s);
    makeQ(ss.getStringState(),null,s);//add the first State to queue
    //s.setG(0);
    //s.setF(s.gettG()+heuristicTwo(ss.getStringState(),goal));
    s.setF(heuristicTwo(ss.toString(),goal));
    while(!states.isEmpty()){
        LinkedList<State>child=new LinkedList<State>();
        State state = lowestF(states);
        StringState pre = new StringState(state);
        if (goalReached(state)&&!solved){
            s = state;
            solved=true;
            System.out.println("#########\n# Solved #\n#########");
            break;
        }
        //explore(state);
        child=neighbours(child,state);
        for(int i=0;i<child.size();i++)
        {
            child.get(i).setTotalCost(state.gettG()+findDistance(state,child.get(i)));
            if(open.containsKey(child.get(i)))
            {
                if(child.get(i).gettG()<=child.get(i).getTotalCost())
                    System.out.println(child.get(i).getSolution());
                    continue;
            }
            else if(close.containsKey(child.get(i)))
            {
                if(child.get(i).gettG()<=child.get(i).getTotalCost())
                    continue;
                System.out.println(child.get(i).getSolution());
                StringState next = new StringState(child.get(i));
                makeQ(next.getStringState(),pre.getStringState(),child.get(i));
                close.remove(child.get(i));
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(child.get(i).getSolution());
                StringState next = new StringState(child.get(i));
                makeQ(next.getStringState(),pre.getStringState(),child.get(i));
                child.get(i).setH(heuristicTwo(next.getStringState(),goal));
            }
            child.get(i).setG(child.get(i).getTotalCost());

        }
        close.put(ss.getStringState(),ss.getStringState());



    }
    solution = s.getSolution();
    if (solution.equals("")||solution.equals(null))
        System.out.println("no solution");
    else{
    System.out.println("Astar");
    System.out.println(solution);
    }
}
```

StringState is just takes the state of the board of the puzzle and converts in to a string.
 to make thins a little more clear here some other parts of the code:

```
              private Queue<State> states;
private State stateToSolve;
boolean solved=false;
private final String goal = "0123456789ABCDEF";
private final String goal2 = "123456789ABCDEF0";

private Map<String,String> close;//to keep track of previous checked status
private Map<String, String> open;
private String solution;

//-1,-1 for decrement of coordinates
private final int up = -4;
private final int down = 4;
private final int left = -1;
private final int right = 1;

//CONSTRUCTOR
public Astar(State s){
    solution = "";
    states = new LinkedList<State>();
    stateToSolve = duplicateState(s);
    close = new HashMap<String, String>();
    open = new HashMap<String, String>();
    solve();

}
```

All the neighbours function does is to take a state of the board and returns the neighbours of the board-meaning moving the blank tile to the left/right/up/down(if possible)and giving back the board state after doing it.
so the neighbours are the new states.

The problem that I'm facing (I came to realize after running the program and tried to print it's state at some points)is that it's going inside an infinite loop apter 2 moves of the blank tile.For example, when I'm trying to find a path for the String str1 = "1 2 0 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F";
the answer should be-left left
but I'm getting

left
left

left
right

left
down

left
left

left
right

left
down

left
left

and it just go on and on infinitelly..
Any help would be appreciated..
((I was using this -[pseudo code](http://mat.uab.cat/~alseda/MasterOpt/AStar-Algorithm.pdf))

Comment: have you try debugging? going step by step and check what is going on?

Comment: Its quite difficult to answer this. A lot of the program is missing and without a complete representative program this sort of debugging is very difficult. I'd also suggest avoiding method names like `gettG` or `makeQ` as what they do is difficult to determine